# Java: how to create a generic class that requires a data type which extends a class and implements an interface?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to create a composite in GWT that require a class which extends a class and implements an interface. Psudo code as below (it does not work apparently):

```
class GridRow<T extends Widget implements HasText> extends Composite{
  //more codes here
}
```

Comment: You cant have "implements" inside `<>`. Explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's written as:

```
class GridRow<T extends Widget & HasText> extends Composite {
    // ...
}
```

You can have `[class or interface]( & [interface])*` (in pseudo regex language).